# online compiler for r-markdown document

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

Is there any online compiler for rmarkdown document? Something like overleaf for latex, but to compile rmarkdown documents instead. It should be online because I'm often working at foreign computers, for example in the university computer lab and they don't have rmarkdown installed.

A short example I'd like to compile

```
---
title: "Title"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
author: "Author"
output: beamer_presentation
---

## Slide 1

- Bullet point 1
- Bullet point 2
```

Comment: https://rstudio.cloud

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I consider https://rstudio.cloud/ a great website for this. Because:

1. You can sign up for the basic plan for free
2. It has a full texlive installation (as far as I can tell)
3. The UI looks and feels pretty much the same as RStudio on a local machine:

[image]

It works so well that I often use it to debug failing documents if I suspect it might be due to my local LaTeX etc configuration.

It is not very powerful though and sometimes even compiling R-packages fails for lack of memory. Also there does not seem to be a straightforward way for collaborating on a project but you can share a link and support for that might come in the future.

There also seems to be some support for knitr and even code execution directly in overleaf (see [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Knitr) and [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/How_to_write_in_Markdown_on_Overleaf)) but I don't know how well this works.